# How to display day from selected date using javafx?

Tags: javafx

I want to know the code how to get the day name of a selected date which select from the datepicker to a textfield using javafx and scenebuilder.

I use “Windows 10,  MySQL 5.7.

this is what i tried. I want to get the day name of date in "txtDate" and set it to txtDay instead of adding it manually.

name of the datepicker field is txtDate)
name of the text field is txtDay)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIIMp.png)

Comment: We're not a "make my code please" forum. Do it by yourself and if you don't get any further, describe your problem and send us the code you have written so far. If you know what you need, you can just google it and you'll find some examples: 
https://o7planning.org/en/11085/javafx-datepicker-tutorial

Comment: The value of a `DatePicker` is a `LocalDate`. Check [the API of that class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) to see what's available.

Answer (score 4):

You should just use `DateTimeFormatter`

Example

```
LocalDate day = LocalDate.now(); // or myDatePicker.getValue()
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE", Locale.getDefault());
System.out.println(day.format(format));
myLabel.setText(day.format(format));
```

You will see what you want "Wednesday"

Answer (score 1):

I have created a program that returns the Day on selecting a date from the **DatePicker**.

This is my main class -

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/main.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This is my Controller class -

```
package application;

import java.time.LocalDate;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class MainController {
    @FXML DatePicker datePicker;
    @FXML Label dayLabel;

    @FXML private void handleDatePickerEvent(ActionEvent e){

        LocalDate localDate = datePicker.getValue();
        dayLabel.setText(localDate.getDayOfWeek().toString());

    }       
}
```

This is my FXML file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="116.0" prefWidth="338.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.102" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MainController">
   <children>
      <DatePicker fx:id="datePicker" layoutX="150.0" layoutY="22.0" onAction="#handleDatePickerEvent" />
      <Label fx:id="dayLabel" layoutX="150.0" layoutY="70.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="142.0" text="Label">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="13.0" />
         </font></Label>
      <Label layoutX="56.0" layoutY="25.0" prefHeight="19.0" prefWidth="86.0" text="Date Picker :">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="13.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="102.0" layoutY="69.0" prefHeight="19.0" prefWidth="37.0" text="Day :">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="13.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

This is the snapshot of my program -

[image]

I hope this helps you!

EDITED : I have used **Label** in this program. You can also use **TextField**.

Comment: this is bad, why convert to `Date` and why `switch case`?

Comment: Yup! That seemed a very bad approach. So I have edited my answer. Now, without converting to `Date` and also without using `switch case`. The task has been achieved.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with just two lines of code.

```
LocalDate localDate = datePicker.getValue();
myLabel.setText(localDate.getDayOfWeek().toString());
```